# JavaScript: Continuously change character

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a `<p>` tag

```
<p id="rev">|</p>
```

that I want to continuously change via Javascript to create an old-school loading animation that would follow this pattern in repetition:

```
| / - \
```

I'm not familiar with how Javascript treats recursion, but the following block of code simply creates a long loading period and doesn't function as intended:

```
function runRev() {
    document.getElementById('rev').innerHTML = "/";
    setTimeout(function(){}, 2000);
    document.getElementById('rev').innerHTML = "-";
    setTimeout(function(){}, 2000);
    document.getElementById('rev').innerHTML = "\\";
    setTimeout(function(){}, 2000);
    document.getElementById('rev').innerHTML = "|";
    setTimeout(function(){}, 2000);
    runRev();
}
runRev();
```

I imagine there is a better way to accomplish this. How can I create a Javascript function that continuously runs to change that single character?

Comment: What this does: Boss: "Note that this door needs to be painted blue. Remember that after two hours you have to do nothing in particular. Now this same door needs to be yellow. Also, in two hours, there's nothing to be done, OK? This door, green. In two hours, nothing. And also this same door, make it red. Additionally, remember to do nothing in two hours." Worker: "Boss, I can't paint that fa..." Boss: "DO IT ALL AGAIN! RIGHT NOW!" Worker, scribbling: "Blue, yellow, green, red, do nothing four times two hours later, blue, yellow, green, red, do 4 nothings later... BOSS, I RAN OUT OF NOTEBOOK!"

Comment: Welcome to the single-threaded nature of JavaScript :) Nothing will happen unless you give the browser some time to paint (and do other things). Specifically, there's no way (until you learn about `await`) to make a function pause without crashing everything. Notably, `setTimeout(function(){}, 2000);` doesn't pause the function for two seconds, it just tells the browser to remember to invoke an empty function sometime after two seconds has passed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This really doesn't require recursion. Just using [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) while looping over a character array will do:

```js
const chars = ['|', '/', '-', '\\'];
const el = document.getElementById('loading');
let i = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  el.innerHTML = chars[i];
  i = (i + 1) % chars.length;
}, 100);
```

```html
<span id="loading"></span>
```

Answer (score 4):

A recursion way may looks like this:

```js
const chars = ['|', '/', '-', '\']
const element = document.getElementById('rev')
function run (count) {
  element.innerHTML = chars[count % chars.length]
  return setTimeout(() => run(count + 1), 2000)
}
run(0)
```

If your browser supports `async/await`:

```js
const chars = ['|', '/', '-', '\']
const element = document.getElementById('rev')

async function run (count) {
  element.innerHTML = chars[count % chars.length]
  await sleep(2000)
  run(step + 1)
}
run(0)

function sleep (duration) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, duration))
}
```

Comment: This will give very weird results once `count` starts overflowing. Probably better to move the modulo operation, and put it in `run((count + 1) % chars.length)`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: It can't overflow in JavaScript. The overflow would happen after `1.7976931348623157e+308` if a sufficiently large number was added; but it would get _stuck_ way before then (I believe at `18014398509481984`, but I could be wrong), when `count + 1` equals `count` due to insufficient precision. (Moving the modulo is still a good idea!)

Comment: @Amadan You're right. For the current version of Chrome, the value seems to be at 9007199254740992.

Comment: Yep, you're right, your number's better than my number :D

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yes, I did not aware of that as it takes really a long time to overflow:D.  Besides, the safe value can be get by `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, which is 9007199254740991 in Chrome.

Comment: Wouldn't want to run into a problem in the year 570,843,861! :D

Comment: The person waiting for *that* spinner is pretty damn patient!

Answer (score 2):

You could use css animation to do this.

```css
@keyframes spinner {
    0% {
        content: "|";
    }
    30% {
        content: "/";
    }
    50% {
        content: "-";
    }
    100% {
        content: "\\";
    }
}

.element::after {
    animation: spinner 0.5s linear infinite;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    content: "|";
}
```

```html
<p class="element"></p>
```

Comment: Close, but this solution looks more like a clockhand revolving around the edge of a radius rather than a baton being rotated at the center axis.

Comment: Except this is not an answer to the question, but a different way of solving the initial problem.

Comment: Yes, I agree, But the question is basically for the animation , The author intention is to get the animation, Maybe the author is not aware of that this can be done with CSS, So I showed him an alternate approach to do this.